# How many prototype objects are in the chain for the following array? let arr = [];

Tags: arrays, object, prototype, chain

How many prototype objects are in the chain for the following array? let arr = [];
The answer is 2.
I am not sure what this question is asking exactly. What should I learn first to understand this question and whey the answer is 2?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is 2 (two)

```js
let arr = [];

// it inherits from Array.prototype
console.log( arr.__proto__ === Array.prototype ); // true : this is first

// then from Object.prototype
console.log( arr.__proto__.__proto__ === Object.prototype ); // true : : this is second

// and null on the top.
console.log( arr.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__ ); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is two. Check out the diagram below that I got from the following link:

https://javascript.info/native-prototypes#other-built-in-prototypes
[image: Image of prototypeChain]